# Mounting HFS+ volume in Linux

Tags: macos, usb, unix, mount, hfs+

I'm not sure if this is the appropriate area to post my question. But I am wondering how can I mount a MacBook Pro mid 2007 HDD on Debian Linux. My MacBook bombed out on me and now I need to attempt to recover some data on the hard drive. What hardware do I need to hook it up through USB and should read privileges be enough to copy from drive to else where?

Comment: This _might_ be more appropriate for the UNIX SE.

Answer (score 1):

You need a SATA to USB connector kit or 2.5" SATA External USB Enclosure, either will do.  Read-Only access is all that you need to retrieve the User Data you want to save.

[Example of SATA to USB connector kit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000YJBL78)

[Example of 2.5" SATA External USB Enclosure](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=0VN-0003-000H3)

Answer (score 1):

1. Standard Debian should be able to mount a HFS+-formatted medium. This is for Ubuntu, but should work for you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/332315/how-to-read-and-write-hfs-journaled-external-hdd-in-ubuntu-without-access-to-os
2. Use a SATA-to-USB-Adaptor, you should be able to buy one for about 15-20 € or $. I've never seen one being incompatible with Linux.
3. I'm not sure, but this should be the appropriate guide for you to disassemble the device and get the hard drive out of there: [IFIXIT](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Core+2+Duo+Model+A1211+Hard+Drive+Replacement/459)